# Ajax response not updating in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a slight problem figuring out why this ajax response isn't updating properly. I have a php while loop which lists gallerys in text format, i am using . It is getting details from the php page but only for one result so essentially when you hover over the name a qtip tooltip box pops up so you can edit the name of the gallery. The problem is it only lists one result for all results in the loop.

PHP & HTML

```
    <?php
            $MemberGalleriesQuery = $bapcity->query("SELECT * FROM CroMemberRetailGalleries WHERE UserID='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY GalleryID DESC");
            $MemberGalleriesCount = $MemberGalleriesQuery->num_rows;

            if ( $MemberGalleriesCount ) 
            {
                $BaseHeight = 150;
                $GalleriesBoxHeight = $BaseHeight + ( 20 * $MemberGalleriesCount );
                echo '
                <div id="ManageGalleries" style="height: '.$GalleriesBoxHeight.'px" align="center">
                <div id="ManageGalleriesHeader">Manage Galleries</font></div><br><br>
                <font color="#000000"><b>Click Gallery To Edit</b></font><br><br>
                ';

                while($GalleryData = $MemberGalleriesQuery->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '>> <b><a class="EditGallery" href="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=EditGallery&gallerykey='.$GalleryData['GalleryID'].'">'.$GalleryData['GalleryName'].'</a></b> <<<br>';
                }

                echo '<br><br></div>';
            }
            $MemberGalleriesQuery->free();
            ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    //Edit Form When Hovering Over Gallery Name
$('.EditGallery').each(function() {


    var link = $('.EditGallery').attr('href'); //Gets link url

    $.ajax({ //Make the ajax request
        url: link,
        cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) { //On complete run tooltip code

        //Display tooltip code goes here, returned text is variable html
    $('.EditGallery').qtip({
        content: {
            text: html
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 300
        },
        style: 'wiki'
    });
    $('.EditGallery').qtip('click', true);
    $(".EditGallery").page();
    });
});
```

CONTENTS OF Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php

```
    if ( isset( $cleanGet['action'] ) && $cleanGet['action'] == 'EditGallery' ){

    $MemberGalleriesQuery = $bapcity->query("SELECT * FROM CroMemberRetailGalleries WHERE GalleryID='".$cleanGet['gallerykey']."' AND UserID='".$SessionUserID."' ORDER BY GalleryID DESC");

    $MemberGalleriesCount = $MemberGalleriesQuery->num_rows;

    if ( $MemberGalleriesCount )
    {       
        $GalleryData = $MemberGalleriesQuery->fetch_assoc();
    }?>

    <form action="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=DoEditGallery&gallerykey=<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID']?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="GalleryName" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="GalleryID" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="DeleteGallery" value="Delete Gallery">
    </form>

    <form action="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=DoEditGallery&gallerykey=<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID']?>" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>NOTE:</b> Letters & Numbers Only</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="GalleryName" size="30" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="OriginalGalleryName" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="GalleryID" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID'] ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="EditGallery" value="Edit Gallery">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php }?>
```

PREVIEW:

http://www.bigjohn863.com/mini-upload-form/uploads/ajaxproblem.png

See how all three are the same results.

Comment: Could you share what is in `Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php`?

Comment: I have updated my post with the contents of Crowork.EditGallery.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $('.EditGallery').each(function()
{
        $(this).qtip({
        content:  {
            text: "Loading...",
            ajax: {
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data, status) {
                  this.set('content.text', data);
                }                
               }

            },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 300
        },
        style: 'wiki'
    });
    $(this).qtip('click', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/st0j8nLy/

Comment: I like the loading... part, however with that updated code it shows the entire page in the tool tip.

Comment: `his.set('content.text', $(data).find('body').html());` replace the "body" with your specific tag

Comment: Hi Madalin, i hope your day is good. I replaced that in the code and changed body to my specific tag .EditGallery but it just keeps saying loading .... in the qtip tool tip.

Comment: This fixed the problem ... Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Edit Form When Hovering Over Gallery Name
$('.EditGallery').each(function() {

var link = $('.EditGallery').attr('href'); //Gets link url
....
```

everytime you are calling $('.EditGallery').  $('.EditGallery'). is an array, you need to change all references to $('.EditGallery') that is within the loop to $(this):

```
var link = $(this).attr('href'); //Gets link url
```

Comment: Hi Mat Taylor, I replaced all instances of $('.EditGallery') to $(this) except for the one $('.EditGallery').each. However, it broke the tooltip now it doesn't show at all.

Comment: From what I can see, you have no elements with class EditGallery

Comment: Hey Mat, yes sir i have class set to EditGallery in the anchor tag. <a class="EditGallery"

Answer (score 1):

You Might be need to create dynamic id so you can call proper ajax. 
please modify your ajax call as below

```
 $gid=$GalleryData['GalleryID'];              
 echo '>> <b><a onclick="editgalary($gid)" id="EditGallery_$gid" href="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=EditGallery&gallerykey='.$GalleryData['GalleryID'].'">'.$GalleryData['GalleryName'].'</a></b> <<<br>';
```

replace this code in while loop.

```
function editgalary(galaryid){
   var link = $('#EditGallery_'+galaryid).attr('href');
//ajax code as it is.
}
```

try and let me konw

Comment: Nitesh, good concept! However, it breaks the tooltip so it doesn't show at all.

Comment: add title attributes in anchor tag.  it will work as tooltip as u want.